# GemFire : CacheLoader : Getting data from external database

Tags: gemfire, geode

cacheloader : Use case

One of main use case where GemFire is used is, where it is used as a fast running cache which holds most recent data (example last 1 month) and all remaining data sits in back-end  database. I mean Gemfire data which is 1 month old  is overflowed to database after 1 month.
However when user is looking for data which was beyond 1 month, we need to go to the database and get the data.
Cache loader is suitable for doing this operation on cache misses and gets data from the database. Regarding cache loader I beleive cache misses is triggered only when we do a Get operation on a key and if the key is missing.

What I do not understand is when the data gets overflowed to back-end, I beleieve no reference exist in Gemfire. Also a user may not know the Key - to do a get operation on Key, he might need to execute a OQL query on some other fields other than key.
How will cache miss be triggered when I don't know the key?

Then how does Cache  loader fits into the overall solution?

Answer (score 0):

Geode will not invoke a CacheLoader during a Query operation.

From the [Geode documentation](http://geode.docs.pivotal.io/docs/developing/outside_data_sources/how_data_loaders_work.html):

> The loader is called on **cache misses during get operations**, and it populates the cache with the new entry value in addition to returning the value to the calling thread.

(Emphasis is my own)