# Getting historical data back to gemfire/geode cache

Tags: gemfire, geode

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059415/gemfire-cacheloader-getting-data-from-external-database). Basically, the geode cache layer will hold the most recent data and historical data has been offloaded to the database, thus no references (keys) to the historical data exist in geode anymore. My question is, how would I get the historical data back to the cache for research purposes? Obviously CacheLoader is not for this purpose.

My current thought is, before the data expires in the cache, copy the keys and certain attributes (as search parameters) of the values to a separate region, just to keep the references there. I am still pretty new to gemfire/geode, I was wondering how other people are doing it.

This actually leads to another question about CacheLoader - if there is a cache miss, that means the entry (both key and value) is not in the cache anymore. How does the application (cache client) know what to ask from the cache?